# Is this real Klingon?

Tags: klingon-language

From the movie [Garden State](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0333766/), there's a scene where a minor character claims to speak Klingon.

After speaking [Klingon], he says the translation is:

> "Kill Kirk", and also, "Hallelujah", depending on the context.

**Can someone please verify that this or isn't Klingon? And, if it is, how accurate is it to what he says it is? How good is his use of the Klingon language?**

Comment: http://skerre.conlang.org/conlangs/klingongardenstate.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, it's not Klingon.

For the record, "Kill Kirk." would be **qIrq yIHoH!**

Not sure what a proper translation of "Hallelujah!" would be. Perhaps **Qapla''a'!** ("Great success!").